# WORDPRESS: add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress-theming, thumbnails

I'm customizing a wordpress theme. And now, my theme doesn't have Feature Image function.
I've tried reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails and found out that I need to add the line: add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); to the function.php and hope that "If your theme was successful in adding support for Post Thumbnails the "Featured Image" metabox will be visible on the on the Edit Post and Edit Page screens." as they said in codex.wordpress... But the magic didn't happen.
I've tried mimicking the TwentyTwenty theme for that but didn't succeed. Also found a lot of asked question here but didn't help much.
I don't know if some more steps needed? Could you please help me out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for a custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I fixed my problem.
- The right name of the file functions.php is in plural noun (functions).
- Including `<?php` and `?>` helps.

I know it maybe basic knowledge. I just post here so that perhaps it is useful for someone.
Full working code for functions.php:

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50 );   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
> ```

please look at the syntax correctly sometimes you may write post_thumbnails and get stuck.
it's

> post-thumbnails

**not**

> post_thumbnails